# "After years of uncertainty and upheaval allowed ISIS militants"

Tags: relative-clauses

*After years of uncertainty and upheaval allowed ISIS militants to gain a foothold in the country, the U.S. has begun carrying out airstrikes to try and oust them.*

Source: http://edition.cnn.com/2016/08/04/africa/libya-chaos-in-graphics/index.html

Don't you think that there is "that" omitted in the sentence above (…upheaval that allowed…). I was thought that when relative pronoun “that” is a subject, you cannot omit the relative pronoun. Or the first clause is not a relative clause?

Comment: It's not a **that** that is missing it is a **which** which is missing.  _After years of uncertainty and upheaval **which** allowed ISIL militants to gain a foothold in the country, the U.S. has begun carrying out airstrikes to try and oust them._

Comment: @JoeDark I think not. _that allowed ISIS militants to gain a foothold in the country_ looks like a restrictive clause to me. The clause is restrictive because without it, _them_ in the second clause has no referent. Thus, either _which_ or _that_ is acceptable here. According to [**Oxford Dictionaries:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/that-or-which) "Restrictive relative clauses can be introduced by that, which, whose, who, or whom."

Comment: @Joe No, bare relatives are ungrammatical when the gap is in subject position, so that parse is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three sentences are grammatical:

After years of uncertainty and upheaval allowed ISIS militants to gain a foothold in the country, the U.S. has begun carrying out airstrikes to try and oust them.

After years of uncertainty and upheaval which allowed ISIS militants to gain a foothold in the country, the U.S. has begun carrying out airstrikes to try and oust them.

After years of uncertainty and upheaval that allowed ISIS militants to gain a foothold in the country, the U.S. has begun carrying out airstrikes to try and oust them.

After weeks of static and interference  made him want to throw the damn phone against a brick wall, he decided to take it into the shop for repair.

After weeks of static and interference that made him want to throw the damn phone against a brick wall, he decided to take it into the shop for repair.

After weeks of static and interference which made him want to throw the damn phone against a brick wall, he decided to take it into the shop for repair.

Comment: But the first one is not a relative clause, isn't it.

Comment: In #1, **allowed** is not part of a relative clause modifying **years of uncertainty and upheaval** with the word **that** having been omitted, as you thought might be the case. The phrase *years of uncertainty and doubt* is the subject of the verb *allowed*.  BTW, you want to ask "is it?" not "isn't it?"

Answer (score 6):

As a learner, I would say it is similar to this pattern:

After (subordinate conjunction) [X happened]**,**  {U.S has done Y}.

I can parse the sentence as below:

> After = subordinate conjunction
>
> Subordinate clause= years of uncertainty and upheaval allowed ISIS militants to gain a foothold in the country.
>
> Main clause: the U.S. has begun carrying out airstrikes to try and oust them

Thus, **years of uncertainty and upheaval** is the subject of the subordinate clause.